# What's the difference between ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh and ReportViewer.RefreshData?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

What's the difference between `ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh` and `ReportViewer.RefreshData`? It is necessary to execute `ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()` before `ReportViewer.RefreshData()` when rendering a local RDLC report, or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Calling the 'ReportViewer.RefreshReport()' method causes all data in the report to be reloaded and rendered. A call to 'ReportViewer.RefreshReport()' is automatically added to the Form Load event handler when a ReportViewer control is added to a form.

If you are only supplying new data but using the same report definition, you may need to call ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh().